# ASP.NET MVC 5 URL Depend on Selection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, seo, url-routing

I have a page created on VS13 MVC 5 based on ASP.NET, on my navigator I have my dropdown menu

[image]

While I click on Phones link I have URL as: www.sitename.com/phones and it will list all phones which I have on my data base, while I choose a brand (e.g: Samsung) I want my URL will be www.sitename.com/phones/samsung

Simple question I don't want create a view for each brand or model of phone because there are a lot, I can just use SQL and list them on the same page but how to change my URL depending on my choice ? Is the only way is Attribute Routing?

Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JS/jQuery you can use the History.js api. https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/

You can then use `History.pushState(insert parameters here);`. This will not only change the url to your choice but also allow users to go back and forward like usual, it also keeps SEO with web crawlers I think.

Comment: I don't think I am gonna use JS/jQuery, thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Route to your route config

in `RouteConfig.cs`

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Product",
            url: "{controller}/{productCategory}/{productName}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", productCategory = UrlParameter.Optional, productName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

in `product controller`

```
public ActionResult index(string productCategory,string productName)
{
     //return items by productCategory/ProductName
}
```

Comment: I guess this is the best option which make sense for me thx :)